# pip install pybluez-win10 ができない

Tags: python, python3, pip

Bitalino apiを使うために pybluze-win10 というものをダウンロードしたいのですが、うまくいきません。
https://github.com/BITalinoWorld/revolution-python-api#prepare-pybluez-installation-on-windows-10

要件が Python > 2.7 or 3.4 と書いてあったため Python 3.4 をインストールしたのち
以下の通り実行しましたがエラーとなりました。

```
> py -3.4 -m pip install pybluez-win10

Downloading/unpacking pybluez-win10
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pybluez-win10
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pybluez-win10
Storing debug log for failure in C:\***\pip\pip.log
```

他の記事に書いてあった方法も試したのですが(-iオプションでhttpsからとってくる,pipのアップグレード)ダメでした。
どなたか有用な方法をご存じありませんか

Answer (score 0):

多分そのサイトとパッケージはPyBluezがWindowsに対応していない頃に作られた物でしょう。
最新の0.23版ではPython3.5から3.7でWindows用のWheelが配布されているので紹介先の手順は不要になっていると思われます。
むしろPython3.4を使う方がPython自身のサポート期間終了も含めて非推奨でしょう。
あと最新版でもDec 28, 2019ということで活発に開発されていない状況と書いてあります。

[PyBluez 0.23 Download files - PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/PyBluez/0.23/#files)
[pybluez/pybluez](https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez)

> Python Version Support
> Python 3 (min 3.5) Version 0.23 and newer
>
> This project is not under active development.

使うならPython3.7の環境を作成してこちらのページを参考にインストールしてみてはどうでしょう？
[pybluez/docs/install.rst](https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez/blob/master/docs/install.rst)

---

それから、上記から分岐して独自に開発している`pybluez2`というパッケージもあるようですね。
こちらは最新版が今年8月20日でPython3.6から3.9までのWindows用のWheelが配布されています。Python自身で3.10がリリースされたので、そのうち対応した版かWheelが出来てくる可能性が考えられます。
Pythonを3.9にしてこちらを試してみても良いのでは？

[pybluez2 0.44 Download files - PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pybluez2/0.44/#files)
[airgproducts/pybluez2](https://github.com/airgproducts/pybluez2)

> Python Version Support
> Windows: >= 3.9

> License
> This library is based on the work that has been put into the original 'PyBluez' library by: